# Using recursion how can i keep the local variable updated

Tags: java, recursion, int

Using recursion how can i keep the local variable updated till a condition is met. I have an instance below that explains why question very well. The count variable is a local variable and very time the method goes through the count is set to 0. I cannot move the count outside the method it has to be local variable not static or anything else.. The desired output should be (3  6)

```
public static int returnInt(int b) {

        int count = 0;

        if (b == 6) {

            System.out.println(count + " " + b);
        }

        b += 2;
        count++;

        return returnInt(b);

    }
```

Comment: Why are you not allowed to change anything?

Comment: Isn't `count` just `int count == b / 2;`? Otherwise you'll have to pass the `count` variable to the recursive function as well.

Comment: You do realize that `returnInt` will never, in fact, return anything, right? :-) Because it won't stop until it crashes with a a stack overflow. (Recursive algorithms **must** have a get-out clause.)

Answer (score 5):

Pass `count` as an additional parameter to the method:

```
public static int returnInt(int b, int count) {

    ... do some stuff to b, print something, check whether end-condition has been met ...

    return returnInt(b, count + 1);
}
```

Then, call `returnInt` with an extra argument of `0` to start things off.

Comment: ...and add logic that provides a termination condition. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -- `check whether end-condition has been met`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Local variable is local by definition. It exists only in scope of current execution of the method.

BUT you have the following solutions.

The best one is to pass it as a parameter of your method (exactly as you do with other parameter `b`.

```
public static int returnInt(int b) {
    return returnInt(b, 0)
}
private static int returnInt(int b, int count) {
    // your code here. 
}
```

If (for some strange reason) you cannot change the method signature you can put this variable into `ThreadLocal`. In this case even if several threads execute your method simultaneously your code stays thread safe.

Moving this variable to class level is the worst solution cause it is not thread safe and breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int returnInt(int b) {
    return returnInt(b, 0);
}

private static int returnInt(int b, int count) {    
    if (b == 6) {
        System.out.println(count + " " + b);
        // My guess is you should be returning something here???

        // Actually, this shouldn't be your exit point from the recursion because depending on the starting value of b, since you are always adding 2, it might never equal 6, so again you would get a StackoverflowException.
    }    
    b += 2;
    count++;

    return returnInt(b, count);
}
```

Comment: My answer is a reflection on the code posted, T. J. Crowder raises the important point that this will never return.

Answer (score 1):

This function will overflow your stack. You must provide a way out when using recursion. And as for the variable count, you are redefining it back to 0 every time; it cannot be initialized inside the recursive function. Try passing it to your function as a parameter, and also providing a way out for your function.

```
public static int returnInt(int b,int count) {

    if (b == 6) {

        System.out.println(count + " " + b);
        return b;
    }
    b+=2;
    count++;
    return returnInt(b);
}
```

the 'return b' line can be your way out...and you don'y necessarily have to return b... return whatever you need.

Comment: Note that if this method is called initially with b as an odd number or already greater than 6 then the exit condition will never be met, so something else has to change.

Comment: that is true, this is just an example to show how you can exit the recursive method

Answer (score 0):

In general, create returnIntInner(int b, *boxed count*), move the bulk of the logic to that, and call that from a "thin" version of returnInt.  To box `count` the "old style" way is to pass the count as an int[1] array, so that it can be returned -- I've not studied up on the new Java reference parm syntax.  But since your code is tail-recursive and doesn't need to access `count` after the recursive call, you can simply pass `count` as a regular parameter.